# Is Recursive Feature Elimination + Random Forest feature ranking an embedded or wrapper feature selection method?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest

Feature ranking in Random Forest is considered a multivariate feature selection method (Filter). And RFE is a wrapper method. 
And I know that embedded methods are a combination of filter + wrapper. So is RF feature ranking + RFE an embedded method?

Comment: It is wrapper method of feature selection

Comment: Further information on the topic: https://towardsdatascience.com/overview-of-feature-selection-methods-a2d115c7a8f7